# Number whose letters are in alphabetical order

Tags: word-problem, number-property

Can you find the smallest number whose letters are in alphabetical order when spelled out in English?

Comment: I believe that this problem is **very** well known, please don't post them here.

Comment: Again I didn't know about this problem - only learned today.

Comment: And the smallest number with REVERSE alphabetical order is ONE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that would be...

> Forty